# Httptest.php error in logs

Tags: php, yii

I am getting index/httptest.php error in my logs ,i don't get the reason why this error is occur. so my question is why this type of url is hit on my  index page and how to solve this error

error is look like this:-

> 2015/12/07 10:42:02 [error] [exception.CHttpException.404] exception
>   'CHttpException' with message 'Unable to resolve the request
>   "httptest.php".' in /var/app/current/framework/yiilite.php:1703 
>   REQUEST_URI=/httptest.php

In access logs-

> "GET /httptest.php HTTP/1.1" 302 - "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux
>   x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/45.0.2454.101
>   Safari/537.36"

this error hit 20 times

Answer (score 0):

Inside file: `/var/app/current/framework/yiilite.php` on line 1703 looks like you have a `GET` function that is trying to get a file called `httptest.php`
most likely your server has been hacked. As this is a known malware.

Comment: That was a property where yii framework throws exception error for invalid request(.php file which is not exists in the project). Seems weird that she is getting so many invalid request on httptest.php.